# Charting API for flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

Can anybody name some API for charting in flex except AmChart.
I want a good API as i am facing too much problem with AmChart API.
Also please provide the links as how to use that API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BirdEye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/), and you can see the demo in [BirdEye Demo](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html) page

Comment: Anymore APIs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody provide sample examples on BirdEye API.

Thanks in advance.